# Cant use a string because of \n?

Tags: python

When running this code I get an error because of the \n at the end of the string. How can I fix this?

```
import urllib
prefix = 'http://archive.outernet.is/'
with open(!file_list.txt, 'r') as f:
    stock = f.read().splitlines()
    for l in stock:
        l = l.strip()
        content =   ("%s%s") % (prefix, l)
        print(content)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(content, l)
```

File list contains

```
1.zip
2.zip
3.zip
```

And the error code goes something like

```
Errno 2, no such file or directory 'website.ca/1.zip\n'
```

Comment: What is `!file_list.txt`?  That is not valid Python.  Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: I would love to, but for some reason I can't select text in terminal, since I'm on android. The file is an arbitrarily named file that should have been in quotes (and is in my code). The code prints the line from the file with a newline and then talks about how the file I'm looking for isn't found, and it's because of the '\n' at the end of it.

Comment: You need to post the actual code you're running.  Otherwise no one can tell if the problem lies between your real code and the code you posted.  I notice there are other inconsistencies in your code (e.g., the prefix is set to Website with capital W but the error message has lowercase w).

Comment: I can't replicate you error, I made a file with the 3 zip names and it prints normally.

Comment: Actual code posted. Good to know, may be qpython on android throwing me for a loop?

Comment: It works fine.
http://archive.outernet.is/1.zip
('1.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02326B98>)
http://archive.outernet.is/2.zip
('2.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02326C10>)
http://archive.outernet.is/3.zip
('3.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02326AA8>)

Comment: Also, the correct use of urllib is urllib.urlretrieve(content, l), not need the request.(it raises AttributeError)

Comment: Really? Would you mind grabbing !file_list.txt from archive.outernet.is and double checking with that file? Also removing the extra request made my code happier, thank you.

Comment: Just did that, works fine:
http://archive.outernet.is/003669cf61a1f17115b0bf74256114ea.zip
('003669cf61a1f17115b0bf74256114ea.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02362BC0>)
http://archive.outernet.is/0051d970f292ef8afb6d46102e90295e.zip
('0051d970f292ef8afb6d46102e90295e.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02362C10>)
http://archive.outernet.is/005f1d942b971216952437097d605cea.zip
('005f1d942b971216952437097d605cea.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02362C88>)
http://archive.outernet.is/006c514d4f3bf10bbff0e4152f8cae38.zip

Comment: I was missing a very small piece of code at that point. Forgot to come back and say so. User error >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip whitespace from each line:

```
for l in stock:
    l = l.strip()
    content =   ("%s%s") % (prefix, l)
    # etc. ...
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't do anything, neither does trying to replace. Would using python 3.2 influence that?

Comment: @UnilGreyeagle: You'll need to show the complete error message in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that I'm running.

```
import urllib.request

prefix = 'http://archive.outernet.is/'
with open("input.txt", 'r') as f:
    stock = f.read().splitlines()
    for l in stock:
        content = ("%s%s") % (prefix, l)
        print(content)
        print(urllib.request.urlretrieve(content, l))
```

Outputs:

```
http://archive.outernet.is/003669cf61a1f17115b0bf74256114ea.zip
('003669cf61a1f17115b0bf74256114ea.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02362BC0>)
http://archive.outernet.is/0051d970f292ef8afb6d46102e90295e.zip
('0051d970f292ef8afb6d46102e90295e.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02362C10>)
http://archive.outernet.is/005f1d942b971216952437097d605cea.zip
('005f1d942b971216952437097d605cea.zip', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x02362C88>)
http://archive.outernet.is/006c514d4f3bf10bbff0e4152f8cae38.zip
...
```

Comment: Since I don't have python 3 in my machine I run your code in this website(http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python3_online.php), it runs just fine. Is there anything else in your that may not work. Try print every variable you have and check where this '\n' is comming from. It makes no sense to me. Also you link is invalid.